# Java BufferedImage set new size

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

I am using a `BufferedImage` to display a single image. I alter the image data by getting the pixel data from `getRaster()` and than changing it. It works great if I only alter pixel values, but if I change the size (width/height) of the pixel data array the new `BufferedImage` won't resize.

Here is the code:

```
bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(img.width, img.height, bufferedImage.getType());
bufferedImage.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0,  img.width, img.height, img.pixels);
```

What else do I have to do so that the `bufferedImage`size is changed?

For example, if I let the pixels array unchanged and just swap width/height (so pixels.length is the same) the image does not change.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that demonstrates the problem? I'm don't understand from the current snippet what is going wrong. If you create an image like `new BufferedImage(height, width, ...)` and `setDataElement(0, 0, height, width, ...)` then the resulting image surely looks different than if you did `(width, height, ...)`

Comment: The code above is what I use. The problem is that the initial BufferedImage had a different width and height and when I re-create the buffered image it doesn't work if it has different size. I think it is not because of it, but because of it's container (ImageIcon and JLabel) not applying the size update.

Comment: The problem is that the code that you posted doesn't demonstrate the issue. It doesn't compile/run. It's best to make a small code snippet that does run and demonstrates your problem, otherwise I doubt that people will be able to answer your question

Answer (score 2):

I think creating a new BufferedImage from it should work:

```
BufferedImage nImg = new BufferedImage(nW, nH, bufferedImage.getType());

Graphics2D g2d = nImg.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

Comment: You are declaring but not using temp above. I don't want to use any unnecessary functions for rescaling as all I want to do is set the `bufferedImage` data to `img.pixels[]`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to draw the new image. If you only want to change the size without scaling it you can skip the scaling part and use your old image. I edited my answer.